# Getting Error Creating Directory In Ubuntu Using Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, testcase, create-directory

I have made a test case of one Method that will call actual Method in it and execute it.

That method is used to create directory.

Following is my code :

**Actual Method :**

```
public String getDefaultFolderPath() {

String path = "";
        try {

            String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
            System.out.println("Os name Identified");
            if (os.toUpperCase().indexOf("WINDOWS") != -1) {
                File file = new File("C:/MARCDictionary");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("11");
                    file.mkdir();
                }

                path = "C:/MARCDictionary";
            } else if (os.toUpperCase().indexOf("LINUX") != -1) {
                File file = new File("/usr/MARCDictionary");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("22");
                    //file.mkdir();
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                path = "/usr/MARCDictionary";
            } 
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return path;
}
```

Test Case :

```
@Test
    public void testGetDefaultFolderPath() {
        System.out.println("getDefaultFolderPath");
        Utilities instance = Utilities.getInstance();
        String expResult = "/usr/MARCDictionary";
        String result = instance.getDefaultFolderPath();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);

    }
```

Gives me an error :

```
getDefaultFolderPath
Os name Identified
22
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at NGLUtility.NGLUtilities.getDefaultFolderPath(Utilities.java:108)
    at utilities.NGLUtilitiesTest.testGetDefaultFolderPath(UtilitiesTest.java:85)

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :/usr/MARCDictionary
```

Any suggestion Please Why it's Happening like this..

I am using `Ubuntu` and `Intellij IDEA.`

Comment: It's happening because `Permission denied`.

Comment: How to give permission to it ? An I am confused that to whom I ll have to give permission ? Any help sir..

Comment: you should run the java program on behalf of the user who has permission to write to specified location. for example, root :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not have write permissions on `/usr` directory. you must give write permissions on this folder or try some other folder within `/usr` that has write permissions. For example to give all the permissions on `/usr` you can use `chmod 777 /usr`

Hope this helps

Comment: It is a bad idea to give 777 permissions to /usr.  Just save your file where it belongs, like under /home/youruser.  Don't go mucking up parts of the operating system where files don't belong.

Comment: @EricLeschinski I completely agree. Thats why i just wrote it for example.